# How to read a protobuf packet from Dart in Python over Http

Tags: python, http, dart, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to pass data around in Protobuf from a Dart backend to a python client app. However, communication between the two seems difficult. The python client doesn't seem to recognize the protobuf packet from the backend.

The Dart code looks like this

```
        var packet = ReturnPacket();
        packet.rfwId = queries["rfwId"].toString();
        packet.lastBatchId = lastBatchId;
        packet.results.addAll(data);

        var return_packet = packet.writeToBuffer();

        return Response.ok(return_packet);
      }
```

And the python client looks like this:

```
        data = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
        parsed_data = data_packet_pb2.ReturnPacket()
        print('Before serialization: '+ data.text)
        print(parsed_data.ParseFromString(data.content))
```

I keep getting this error:

```
    print(parsed_data.ParseFromString(data.content))
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Any Idea why?